# Value of an attribute node with a concat in select

Tags: xml, xslt

Got a little probleme here. I want to print the value of an attribute node but with a concat in the `xsl:value-of`'s select.

Like that (I'm already in the targeted node) :

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('@', $categories)"/>
```

But when i'm trying to do it this way it just print me the result of the concat method.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't construct dynamic XPath expressions like that, but in this case you don't need to.  If you want the value of the attribute whose *name* is contained in the `categories` variable then you can achieve that with

```
<xsl:value-of select="@*[name() = $categories]"/>
```

Comment: Thanks mate ! It works perfectly, can you explain me why I can't do what I tried ? And what your code is doing ?

Comment: @Toodoo in your example the `value-of` evaluates the `concat` expression, which returns a string, to return the attribute value it would have to take that strong, compile it as an expression and then evaluate that again. My code extracts the set of all attribute nodes on the current element (`@*`) and then filters that set using a _predicate_ to find just the one with the right name. If there is no attribute with that name the result of the filtering will be the empty set, whose `value-of` is the empty string.